# how to use new scala 2.8.0 nested annotations

Tags: scala, persistence, annotations, scala-2.8, java-ee-6

looks like when scala 2.8.0 is out, we can use nested @annotations in our persistence layers. But how? Can anyone please transform this from java to scala? Thanks.

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findAll", query="select p from Person p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "findTheOne",
          query="select p from Person p where p.name = 'Neo'")
})
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to wrap the elements in an `Array()` and write the nested annotations like a constructor call:

```
@NamedQueries(Array(
    new NamedQuery(name = "findAll", query="select p from Person p"),
    new NamedQuery(name = "findTheOne",
          query="select p from Person p where p.name = 'Neo'")
))
```

Comment: so one more problem emerged: for
`Stateless(name="Bean")
Bean{...}`
I' ve got
`error: expected start of definition`

Comment: @coubeatczech for top level annotations you cannot omit the '`@`'. I do not know the context of that error but did you mean to write `@Stateless(name="Bean") class Bean { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: sorry, I wrote this without checking if the typed text corresponds the thought, and yes, I meant this: `@Stateless(name="Bean") class Bean{...}`

Comment: Well, I wasted my 1 hour figuring this out and then I found this. Works like charm!